# How to use django-redis package?

Tags: python, django, redis, django-redis

I am new to `redis(No-SQL)`. I am using `django-redis` package in my project. How to configure database `settings` in my settings.py file ?. Is there way need to use other databases like `MySql` etc. If any one knows please explain me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use django ORM with redis out of box. It's not relational database. You can make own mapper, or try replace it with redisco https://github.com/kiddouk/redisco. Should working, but you will propably have many problems using redis as only database engine.

Why you don't use normal relational database? It's better solution. Redis is good for storing fast changing data. For example votes, or last actions on page. If you want use django-redis on view, import class Redis from redis, create instance, and you will have object with methods same as in redis docs.